# Mysqli query error outside class

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a db connection class like this :

```
class db_connector{

const host = "localhost"; 
const user = "root"; 
const password = ""; 
const dbname = "test"; 

public $db;

public function __construct()
{
    $database = $this::dbname;
    $db = new mysqli($this::host, $this::user, $this::password, $this::dbname);
    if($db->connect_errno)
    {
        die (mysql_connect_error());
    }
    return $db;
}
}
```

When i create an object for the class it works fine enough, though then i want to make a query within the class i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method db_connector::query()

The object is as follows (outside the class):

```
$con = new db_connector;
$con->query("SELECT * FROM test");
```

The connection gets established, just the query gives the error. I thought the object would inherit the mysqli methods since I returned it. Can anybody help me fix this one? Im fairly new in OOP so maybe my logic is not the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a little magic:

```
class db_connector{

protected $connectionData = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname' => 'test',
);

protected $db;

public function __construct($connectionData=array())
{
    $cd = array_merge($this->connectionData, $connectionData);
    $this->db = new mysqli($cd['host'], $cd['user'], $cd['password'], $cd['dbname']);

    if($this->db->connect_errno)
    {
        die (mysql_connect_error());
    }
}

public function foo()
{
    return 'I am foo, i exist so i will be called even if mysqli::foo would exist, because i am defined in this class!';
}

public function __get($property)
{
    if(property_exists($this->db, $property)){
        return $this->db->$property;
    }  
}

public function __call($name, $args)
{
    if(method_exists($this->db, $name))
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->db, $name), $args);
}
}
```

And call it like:

```
$db = new db_connector();
$result = $db->query('SELECT foo FROM bar LIMIT 1');
// this should also work:
echo $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly!  Could you jsut explain how? And what I did wrong?

Comment: It's simple, just calling php's magic method __call (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) which is invoked when a method in your class is not found.
In your case, you wanted $object->query() but your class didn't had it, but mysqli did, so just take advantage of that and call it :)
Of course, you could just use your class to extend mysql class, but i wanted to be magic :)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Just another small question. How do i use this with further mysqli statements? Like the following:
`$db = new db_connector();
$query = $db->query('SELECT * from test');
$rows = $db->num_rows($query);
echo $rows;`

Wich does not work (function num_rows does not seem to exsist)

Comment: when you invoke new db_connector() you have access to all the public methods from mysqli, it's just like you would instantiate mysqli() directly. If the mysqli class has a num_rows() method you will have access to it, just use your class as you would use a simple mysqli() instance. See entire docs here http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php
A note, it is num_rows not num_rows() because it is a property not a method. I'll update the class to include the magic __get, stay tuned :)

Comment: It gives the following notice: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: var_dump($result) to see what it returns, might be null/false.
Anyway, i don't really know how mysql works since i don't use it.
You may need to $db->num_rows instead of $result->num_rows, just use mysqli documentation to find out. 
As the class goes, it should work just fine as it just "extends" the mysqli one.

Comment: Sorry it seemed i messed up something. It does work! thanks alot!! For other people, the object works in the following way:
`$db = new db_connector();
$result = $db->query('SELECT * from tset');
echo $result->num_rows;
while($res = $result->fetch_assoc() )
{
 echo $res['username'].'<br/>';
}`

Answer (score 0):

The class constructor won't return the mysqli object as you expect.

```
$con = new db_connector;
//$con is a db_connector object not a mysqli object
$con->query("SELECT * FROM test");
```

Try:

```
$con = new db_connector;
$con->db->query("SELECT * FROM test");
```

instead. $con->db is a public field which holds the mysqli object.

### Edit

Also change:

```
$db = new mysqli($this::host, $this::user, $this::password, $this::dbname);
if($db->connect_errno)
{
    die (mysql_connect_error());
}
return $db;
```

To:

```
$this->db = new mysqli($this::host, $this::user, $this::password, $this::dbname);
if($this->db->connect_errno)
{
    die (mysql_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: It gives the following error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www...`

Comment: I've edited the answer to solve one more problem. Without $this->db you never assign the mysqli() object to your db_connector->db field.

Comment: it is not $this::host but self::host because you reference a constant from your own class scope, and so on. Also constants should be uppercase, etc...

Comment: Thanks! it works! So basicly I never truly assigned the mysqli object to my db object.